# Well-formed <script>Javascript</script> tags confuse Nokogiri::HTML in STRICT mode

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, nokogiri, libxml2

Here's the test case illustrating the problem:

```
def test_strict_Nokogiri
  html = "<script> $('<a></a>') </script>"  
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html, nil, nil, Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions::STRICT)  
  assert_empty doc.errors
end
```

That assertion fails because there are `errors`: `#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Unexpected end tag : a>`.

Even if Nokogiri kept looking for HTML tags inside the `<script>` tags, it should see that the `<a ...>` and `</a>` tags are balanced, right?

How do I get Nokogiri to recognize valid HTML, bypassing embedded Javascript, and only complaining if it's really broken?

EDIT:  I have passed the bug to the libxml2 maintainers:  https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=795390

Comment: Is that really valid? I know `script` needs a `type` attribute in HTML4.

Comment: I discovered the issue parsing a complete web page with its `<script type>` attribute. And, before someone edited my post, the line and column numbers in the error message pointed to the `</a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove script tags from the Nokogiri element you can do this,

```
html = '<div> Hello </div> <script> $("<div></div>") </script>'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html, nil, nil, Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions::STRICT)
doc.text # " Hello   $(\"<div>\") "
doc.xpath('//script').remove
doc.text # " Hello  "
```

And `doc.to_html` would return this

```
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body>\n<div> Hello </div> </body></html>\n"
```

Comment: I'm trying to write an assertion that HTML is well-formed - with its `<script>` tags. In other environments I would shell to Tidy-HTML5, but not this one.

Comment: @Phlip Got it, so if I understand you right, you need to know why nokogiri is behaving this way. Correct?